# Local Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, debian

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-7

I followed the steps shown in above link

```
#mkdir -p /var/www/smartschool.com/public_html
#chown rushabh:rushabh -R /var/www/smartschool.com
#chmode 755 -R /var/www/smartschool.com
#vi /var/www/smartschool.com/public_html/idex.html
#cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/smartschool.com
#vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/smartschool.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@smartschool.com
    ServerName smartschool.com
    ServerAlias www.smartschool.com [...]
#a2ensite smartschool.com
#service apache2 restart
```

now my firefox is showing me
**Not Found**
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at smartschool.com Port 80

did I miss any thing? thank you in advance

Comment: did you update your hosts file also?

Comment: yup i updated /etc/host with 127.0.0.1 smartschool.com and without that ... in both case its not working... 
when 127.0.0.1 smartschool.com is not written browser search for page and finally show me problem loading page

Comment: Did you set `DocumentRoot`? Is there a `Directory` directive referring to the `DocumentRoot` that grants access? Did you close `</VirtualHost>`?

Comment: nope still not working